# Optimization With Dates and Events

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, algorithm

This is a bit of a tricky problem to explain but I will try my best.

I have a calendar of events. In these there are non-working days. When any part of an event lands in on on a non-working day, its days are extended until it reaches a working day.
See here:

I have an orange 1 day event.
[image]

When it is dragged to the non-working day, it extends:

[image]

This works great and works fine.  Here is the problem. I only show 2 weeks of the calendar at a time.  Therefore, first, I fetch the visible events that start, end or fall in the range.  Then, I fetch the nonworking days for the range and dynamically add the non-working days to its length.

Here is where the problem is:

Say there is an event that starts Jan 28th and ends Jan 29th. This means it will not get fetched. But because of Non-Working Days, it would end up on Feb 6th lets say. Well because I did not fetch it in my first step, I will not see it from feb 4 to 15.  That is essentially my problem.

The naive solution would be to grab all events and all non-working days and then pre-calculate all end days dynamically, then filter the visible ones there. But that will get very expensive very fast.

But I cannot think of any other solution. It needs to be dynamic.  Does anyone have any creative ideas on how I could solve this in a non O(N^2) manner.  Just a general outline of a solution would be very helpful. I do not mind modifying the db if needed.

Currently a schedule has a start date and Hours. I dynamically calculate an event's length because different employees work different hours which is why I cannot have static end dates.

Comment: So you want to know when the event will start and end, taking into account non–working days, without actually calculating the start and end, taking into account non–working days?

Comment: Can we see snippets of your code where you handle the events? Makes it easier to come up with a customized solution.

Comment: Why do you have to recalculate the end dates every time they are fetched?  Why can't the end dates be corrected when the event is created and every time a non-working day is added/removed?

Comment: Because I would have to do that when an event is moved too and the calendar allows dragging them around.